# Mikro Orm with nestjs does not load entities automatically

Tags: nest, mikro-orm

I'm trying to make a nestjs project with Mikro Orm refrencing [load-entities-automatically](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/mikroorm#load-entities-automatically). But Mikro Orm does not create tables automatically... The following codes are my settings

**AppModule.ts**

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MikroOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgresql',
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'test',
      password: 'test',
      dbName: 'test',
      port: 5440,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      entities: ['../entity/domain'],
      entitiesTs: ['../entity/domain'],
      allowGlobalContext: true,
      schemaGenerator: {
        createForeignKeyConstraints: false,
      },
    }),
    UserModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**UserModule**

```js
@Module({
  imports: [UserEntityModule],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService, UserRepository],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

**UserRepository**

```js
import { InjectRepository } from '@mikro-orm/nestjs';
import { EntityRepository } from '@mikro-orm/postgresql';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class UserRepository {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly userRepository: EntityRepository<User>,
  ) {}

  async save(req: UserSaveRequest) {
    const response = await this.userRepository
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .insert(req)
      .execute();

    return response;
  }
}
```

**UserEntityModule**

```js
import { MikroOrmModule } from '@mikro-orm/nestjs';

@Module({
  imports: [MikroOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  exports: [MikroOrmModule],
})
export class UserEntityModule {}
```

**User**

```js
import { Entity, Property } from '@mikro-orm/core';

@Entity({ tableName: 'users' })
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @Property({ comment: "user's nickname" })
  nickname: string;
}
```

**BaseEntity**

```js
export abstract class BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryKey()
  id: number;
}
```

Code is simple but too long... How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few notes about what you are doing that might help:

- don't export `MikroOrmModule`, the providers are automatically exported, this is not doing what you think
- you should never use global context, `allowGlobalContext: true` is there to allow unit testing mainly, you will fall into memory leaks and instable response issues if you use only the global context. you are doing it wrong if your app does not work without it.
- `autoLoadEntities` is an alternative to the `entities/entitisTs` options, don't mix them

Answer (score 0):

okey,
so first, could you tell me how your code structure looks like? or atleast provide where is file `UserEntityModule` and `User`

second, try to import the `User` entity manually into `MikroOrmModule`

```
    MikroOrmModule.forRoot({
      //... your code
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      entities: [User],
      // entitiesTs: ['../entity/domain'], // comment if you are not using any class-validator or ts-schema validator.
      //... your code
    }),
    UserModule,
```

then see what the effect...